# javascript object filter - not returning associative keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, underscore.js

Using underscorejs I can filter the data in an object, but it doesn't preserve the keys of it. Is there any way to get back object with keys

```
var data = {
  foo: 'fff',
  bar: 'sss',
  aaa: 'gggg'
}
console.info('returns array with keys:')

console.log(data)

var ret = _.filter(data, function(el, key) {
  if (key == 'foo' || el == 'sss') {
    return true
  }
})

console.info('keys are lost?')
console.log(ret)
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7L7tmq7s/

Comment: You don’t have an array, you have an object.

Comment: updated the code - any thoughts how to solve this please?

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#filter: _“Looks through each value in the list, returning an __array__ of all the values that pass a truth test (predicate).”_ – so this is the wrong method to use for this to begin with.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `pick` rather than `filter`. Replace _.filter with _.pick and your code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out with out filter:

```
console.log(data)
var filtered = {};
var ret = _.each(data, function(el, key) {
  if ((key == 'foo' || el == 'sss')) {
    filtered[key] = el;
  }
})

console.info('keys are not lost?')
console.log(filtered)
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fev5achx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What about something straight like this (underscore is a bit useless here) ?

```js
'use strict';
function ReBuildArray(source, pick, plus) {
    var retVal = {};
    for(var pck in pick) { // without check will return pick'sKey:undefined
        if(source[pick[pck]]) retVal[pick[pck]] = source[pick[pck]];
    }
    for(var pls in plus) {
        retVal[pls] = plus[pls];
    }
    return retVal;
}

var data = {
  foo: 'fff',
  bar: 'sss',
  aaa: 'gggg'
}

var ret = ReBuildArray(data, ['foo','sss']);

console.info('filtered keys', ret); // {foo: "fff"}

var ret = ReBuildArray(data, ['foo','sss'], {'foo2':'bar'});
console.info('filtered keys + additional', ret); // {foo: "fff", foo2: "bar"}

ret = ReBuildArray(data, ['foo','sss'], {'foo':'bar'});
console.info('filtered, but then rewritten keys', ret) // {foo: "bar"}
```